# Typescript does not compile on cloned repository

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I've created an Angular2-component and want to share the code with my colleagues. I've uploaded the code to github, cloned the repo, did `npm install` and `npm run tsc`, but got:

```
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(48,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(44,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(116,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(132,110): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(158,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(160,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(12,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/component_fixture.d.ts(73,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.d.ts(85,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.d.ts(134,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts(52,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts(46,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(69,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(69,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(40,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(41,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(2,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/my.component.spec.ts(40,13): error TS2697: An async function or method must return a 'Promise'. Make sure you have a declaration for 'Promise' or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
src/my.service.ts(59,28): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Cmp[]'.
src/my.service.ts(59,34): error TS7006: Parameter 't' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/my.service.ts(71,43): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'PartCmp[]'.
src/my.service.ts(71,49): error TS7006: Parameter 'pt' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/other.service.spec.ts(122,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(27,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(28,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(35,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
```

This is my npm setup:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.37",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
}
```

and my tsc-compiler setup

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }, "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've already tried deleting node_modules/, typings/, changing the dependencies to the current dependencies from the angular starter, but I just got more error-messages.

Can anyone help me? My ultimate goal is for someone to get clone my repository, run `npm install` and `npm run tsc`, and be ready to develop.

Update1:
Turning es5 to es6 removed the errors regarding the promises; the jasmine-errors are still there:

```
src/other.service.spec.ts(122,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(27,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(28,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/other.service.spec.ts(35,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
```

Update2:

I've updated the dependencies to match the angular-quickstart (https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json). Now it works, thanks for the help!

Comment: Try changing target to es6. Promises are an es6 feature.

Comment: `node -v` `npm -v` and paste it here. Are you using cli?

Comment: node -v: v6.9.5

Comment: Thanks, the es5 to es6 did changes to the promise-errors; I've updated the question

Comment: Yap, you need to install types as npm packages (in this case, `@types/jasmine`). For future reference, use http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/ to see which external modules needs to have the @types library installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing declarations for Promise and some Array methods in your **tsconfig.json**. Note the addition of the `"lib"` property below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }, 
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Furthermore, as noted by @rpadovani you are missing some @types packages for test frameworks.

While some in comments suggested that you change from `"target": "es5"`, to `"target": "es2015"`, this is a choice you must make very carefully as it restricts the set of browsers that can target ***dramatically*** unless you intend to introduce a secondary transpiler.

In this case there is likely no need to update the `"target"` property as `Array` methods like `find` can be supplied by a polyfill, such as core-js, and Angular 2 itself polyfills a global `Promise` by way of depending on zone.js. So do not be overly hasty to update `"target"`, and instead consider configuring the `"lib"` option to obtain the type information that targets the newer runtimes/polyfills.

It is worth noting that updating the `"target"` option is a way to implicitly update the `"lib"` option which is why it was suggested. However, updating `"target"` also changes the degree of syntactic downleveling that is performed by TypeScript when it transpiles your code.

Consider

**source TypeScript**

```
class A {
    http = new Http();
    async retrieve() {
        const data = await this.http
            .get('api/settings')
            .map(r => r.json() as Settings)
            .toPromise();
        const withId = { ...data, id: 1 };
    }
}
```

**emitted JavaScript** `"target": "es5"`

```
"use strict";
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || Object.assign || function(t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t;
    return { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) };
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = y[op[0] & 2 ? "return" : op[0] ? "throw" : "next"]) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [0, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.http = new Http();
    }
    A.prototype.retrieve = function () {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var data, withId;
            return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, this.http
                            .get('api/settings')
                            .map(function (r) { return r.json(); })
                            .toPromise()];
                    case 1:
                        data = _a.sent();
                        withId = __assign({}, data, { id: 1 });
                        return [2 /*return*/];
                }
            });
        });
    };
    return A;
}());
```

**emitted JavaScript** `"target": "es2015"`

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.http = new Http();
    }
    retrieve() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            const data = yield this.http
                .get('api/settings')
                .map(r => r.json())
                .toPromise();
            const withId = Object.assign({}, data, { id: 1 });
        });
    }
}
```

**emitted JavaScript** `"target": "es2017"`

```
"use strict";
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.http = new Http();
    }
    async retrieve() {
        const data = await this.http
            .get('api/settings')
            .map(r => r.json())
            .toPromise();
        const withId = Object.assign({}, data, { id: 1 });
    }
}
```

**emitted JavaScript** `"target": "esnext"`

```
"use strict";
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.http = new Http();
    }
    async retrieve() {
        const data = await this.http
            .get('api/settings')
            .map(r => r.json())
            .toPromise();
        const withId = { ...data, id: 1 };
    }
}
```